# Vuepress adding a font

Tags: fonts, vuepress

I have add in the index.styl the following:

```
body {
   font-family: "Nunito-SemiBold", Helvetica, san-serif
}
```

But when building and deploying on the server, the fond doesn't show.

I tried even to put it on the root directory (the same as index.html).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I added [Plex](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/ibm-plex-serif?subsets=latin) font after downloading it to `theme/assets/fonts` after that I created other stylus file to define font like below:

**fonts.styl**

```
 @font-face
   font-family 'IBM Plex Sans'
   font-style normal
   src url('~@theme/assets/fonts/IBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf')
```

**index.styl**

```
/**
 * Custom Styles here.
 *
 * ref：https//v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#index-styl
 */
@require 'fonts'
    
    *
      font-family 'IBM Plex Sans' !important
```

[image]